# how to change color of input type date with min and max (locked month or year) on chrome

Tags: html, css, date, input

i have the following

```
<input type="date" max="2014-10-20" min="2014-10-10">
```

in chrome, the year and month are locked so you can't change them by choosing them and going up and down by the arrow keys.

also, they have a gray color
how can I change the color of them?

and doing this

```
<input type="date" style="color:red;" max="2014-10-20" min="2014-10-10">
```

only changes the color of the day and slash between the day, month, and year

Comment: Changing the color of native inputs is usually not really feasible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done like:

```
input[type="date"] {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}
```